# How do I assert an Integer value against a String value

Tags: karate

I have

```
responseA = {"auditId": 100}
```

and

```
responseB = {"message": "auditId 100"}
```

How do I assert `responseB` (string value) contains `responseA` (integer value)?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
* def responseA = { "auditId": 100 }
* def responseB = { "message": "auditId 100" }
* match responseB.message contains responseA.auditId + ''
```